# $.each() jQuery newsfeed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to make a newsfeed work on my website. It shows all the news and loops all of them but expired ones. I am able to add news via a webpage, so the JSON may constantly change. The PHP script is generating JSON as the following :

```
[
    {
    "0": "Monsieur",
    "1": "X",
    "2": "24",
    "3": "236",
    "4": "Artichauts",
    "5": "4",
    "6": "2015-06-19",
    "7": "2015-06-26",
    "8": "9",
    "9": "7",
    "nom": "Monsieur",
    "prenom": "X",
    "id_promotion": "24",
    "id_commercant": "236",
    "article": "Artichauts",
    "rubrique": "4",
    "date_debut": "2015-06-19",
    "date_fin": "2015-06-26",
    "prix_origine": "9",
    "prix_promotion": "7"
},
{
    "0": "Monsieur",
    "1": "X",
    "2": "23",
    "3": "236",
    "4": "Betteraves",
    "5": "4",
    "6": "2015-06-18",
    "7": "2015-06-25",
    "8": "8",
    "9": "6",
    "nom": "Monsieur",
    "prenom": "X",
    "id_promotion": "23",
    "id_commercant": "236",
    "article": "Betteraves",
    "rubrique": "4",
    "date_debut": "2015-06-18",
    "date_fin": "2015-06-25",
    "prix_origine": "8",
    "prix_promotion": "6"
}
]
```

And my jQuery script is (trying) to show them

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function newsfeed() {
        $.getJSON("newsfeed.php", function (result) {
            var htmldata = "";
            $.each(result, function (key) {
                $("#news").html(result[key].nom + " " + result[key].prenom + " has a special offer : " + result[key].article + " at " + result[key].prix_promotion + "€ instead of " + result[key].prix_origine + "€ ").delay(5000).slideUp(300)
                    .delay(500)
                    .fadeIn(400);
            });
            x = setTimeout(function () {
                newsfeed()
            }, 5000);
        });
    }
    newsfeed();
});
```

So this code is constantly outputting

> Monsieur X  has a special offer : Betteraves at 6€ instead of 8€

So my problem is, the $.each() function is not working as I'd like to. If someone has an idea, I would appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

`$("#news").html` inside the loop is replacing the entire contents of `#news` with the looped element.

Create all the html inside the `each` and inject it into the div after completing the loop.

```
    var htmldata = '' ;
    $.each(result, function(key){
        htmldata += result[key].nom + " " + result[key].prenom + " has a special offer : " + result[key].article + " at " + result[key].prix_promotion + "€ instead of " + result[key].prix_origine + "€ ";
    });
    $('#news').html(htmldata);
```

Comment: I've tried using this, but it outputs
 **Monsieur X has a special offer : Abricots at 7€ instead of 6€ Monsieur X has a special offer : Beurre at 30€ instead of 5€ Monsieur X has a special offer : Artichauts at 9€ instead of 7€ Monsieur X has a special offer : Betteraves at 8€ instead of 6€**

Comment: Wrap the contents inside whatever html element you want. `html += <html-element>bla bla</html-element>`

Comment: It's still not working, nothing is now showing after adding html elements like span. I've tried doing this :
`htmldata += "<span class="news>" + result[key].nom + " " + result[key].prenom + " has a special offer : " + result[key].article + " at " + result[key].prix_origine + "€ instead of " + result[key].prix_promotion + "€ </span>";`

Answer (score 0):

as Swaraj mention its because of .html which is replacing all the content  .so for that you can take a array push every value in it then make pass that array into .html

```
var arr=[]
 $.each(result, function (key) {
         arr.push(result[key].nom + " " + result[key].prenom + " has a special offer : " + result[key].article + " at " + result[key].prix_promotion + "€ instead of " + result[key].prix_origine + "€ "));
                     });
 $("#news").html(arr);
```

Comment: This changes nothing, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
var i = 0;
function newsfeed(){
$.getJSON('newsfeed.php', function(result){
    var htmldata = '';
    $.each(result, function(key){
        if(typeof result[i]=="undefined") {
            i=0;
        }
        htmldata = '<span id="news-'+ i +'">' + result[i].nom + ' ' + result[i].prenom + ' has a special offer : ' + result[i].article + ' at ' + result[i].prix_origine + '€ instead of ' + result[i].prix_promotion + '€ </span>';
    });
    $('#news')
    .html(htmldata);
    i++;
    x = setTimeout(function(){newsfeed()}, 5000);
});
} 
newsfeed();
});
```

Anyway thank's a lot for your help !